# KATE GUI - KDE - How to insert date in KDE snippet script?

Tags: kde, kubuntu, plasma, kate

When running Kate snippets, I do not know how to use the date variable in a snippet. When I am trying to create a personal snippet where the current date can be inserted such as

Snippet #A-1

```
<!--Edit by Julien
    Date:
    Change Description:
-->
```

Kate snippets returns

```
<!--Edit by Julien
    Date:
    Change Description:
-->
```

instead of the following desired output #A-2 below.

Snippet A-2

```
<!--Edit by Julien
    2019-04-07 23:19:11:
    Change Description:
-->
```

Screenshots
[image: https://i.imgur.com/3Hc1rI3.jpg]
[image]

Comment: 1) Presumably you talking about Kate Snippets (not KDE snippets)? (2) What are "output #A-1" and "output #A-2"? (3) Please summarise the contents of the video here, in text. We don't really want to watch you type! Summarising it here also prevents against link rot, is better for screen readers, etc.

Comment: 1) Yes - it is `Kate Snippets`
2a) Output #A-1 is what I am entering as a Kate code snippet.
`<!--Edit by Julien
    Date
    Change Description:
-->`
2b) Output #A-2 is the desired output based on a using a date variable to insert the current date and time. So I am entering #A-1, to get the desired outcome style of 
A-2 '<!--Edit by Julien
    2019-04-07 23:19:11
    Change Description:
-->'


3) Yes, I apologize I am new here and good manners are lacking.

Comment: No worries at all. That looks much better now. Welcome to U/L! I don't have much experience with Kate, but hopefully someone else can help you. If you get nothing useful here, you can always try the [KDE forums](https://forum.kde.org/), where people are generally quite helpful!

Comment: Yeah I posted in KDE forums too, might have better luck there. I will update the question once I get a solution. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution here:

Snippets:

- Raw output

  ```
  ${t = (new Date()).toISOString()}
  ```

  Result:

  ```
  2023-09-14T12:19:18.146Z
  ```
- With some post-processing

  ```
  ${t = (new Date()).toISOString().slice(0, 19).replace("T", " ")}
  ```

  Result:

  ```
  2023-09-14 12:21:52
  ```